# Python Dataframe Calculate Daily Energy from hourly power data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am having a data frame with hourly power data. I want to compute daily energy.

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'power':np.arange(1.0,9.0)},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=8))
df['energy'] = xdf['power'].resample('1D').sum()
```

Present output:

```
df = 
                     power  energy
2020-05-04 08:00:00  1.0     NaN
2020-05-04 09:00:00  2.0     NaN
2020-05-04 10:00:00  3.0     NaN
2020-05-04 11:00:00  4.0     NaN
2020-05-04 12:00:00  5.0     NaN
2020-05-04 13:00:00  6.0     NaN
2020-05-04 14:00:00  7.0     NaN
2020-05-04 15:00:00  8.0     NaN
```

There is something wrong in my calculations and I see NaN only? How to compute the daily energy? Is it just summing the power? do we need to multiply time and how do we do it?

Comment: Try instead: `df['energy'] = df['power'].resample('1D').transform(sum)`.

Comment: @mechanical_meat Thanks a ton. It solved the problem. I do have a question? is this the right way to calculate `energy`?

Comment: @mechanical_meat Similarly, how do you compute mean and store it?